# Console.error: no permission handler detected.(React Native)

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

I am coding a simple react native app and am getting a console error when I run the app. It says that there is no permission handler detected and tells me to go through some steps. But I do not know how to do these steps, and if they don't work, I don't know how to solve the problem.

Here is the error:

[image]

Here is the podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

def add_flipper_pods!(versions = {})
  versions['Flipper'] ||= '~> 0.33.1'
  versions['DoubleConversion'] ||= '1.1.7'
  versions['Flipper-Folly'] ||= '~> 2.1'
  versions['Flipper-Glog'] ||= '0.3.6'
  versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'] ||= '~> 0.0.4'
  versions['Flipper-RSocket'] ||= '~> 1.0'

  pod 'FlipperKit', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'

  # List all transitive dependencies for FlipperKit pods
  # to avoid them being linked in Release builds
  pod 'Flipper', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-DoubleConversion', versions['DoubleConversion'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-Folly', versions['Flipper-Folly'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-Glog', versions['Flipper-Glog'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-PeerTalk', versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-RSocket', versions['Flipper-RSocket'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/Core', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/CppBridge', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBDefines', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configuration => 'Debug'
end

# Post Install processing for Flipper
def flipper_post_install(installer)
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'YogaKit'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'LocalMainStreet' do
  # Pods for LocalMainStreet
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'

  target 'LocalMainStreetTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  add_flipper_pods!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'LocalMainStreet-tvOS' do
  # Pods for LocalMainStreet-tvOS

  target 'LocalMainStreet-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just have to install RN Permissions and make changes to the podfile and info.plist. Depending on what you need the permissions for, you get the pods. If you're not sure, do them all. You can find the code at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions. There are also some other things you may have to do-those I didn't talk about but are in the npm documentation in the link.

Thanks to @Raghav Herugu for helping me solve the problem

Comment: I have faced the same problem in my project. I have missed doing pod install after updating the pod file with permissions.

Answer (score 17):

Added these in podFile

```
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways/Permission-LocationAlways.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse/Permission-LocationWhenInUse.podspec"
```

Then run `pod install`
For me this worked.

Comment: Could you please explain why that works?

Comment: simply its a path correction @PhilippLehmann

Answer (score 15):

If you are using `use_frameworks!` (for example for firebase app)

add the following to convert all permission pods into static libraries, according to the [docs](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions#workaround-for-use_frameworks-issues).

```
pre_install do |installer|
  Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}

  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    if pod.name.eql?('RNPermissions') || pod.name.start_with?('Permission-')
      def pod.build_type;
        Pod::BuildType.static_library
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Add necessary permissions for your app after `use_react_native!(...)`:

```
use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => false,
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
  )

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-LocationAccuracy', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAccuracy"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse"
```

Clean your project in **XCode => Product => Clean Project**
Clean Derived data:

> rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

*Note*: **Close the IOS Simulator**

Also you can go to ios folder and delete **Podfile.lock** and **Pods** folder.

Install the pods:
`npx pod-install` or `cd ios && pod install`

Try to run your app.

> `yarn ios`
> or
> `npm run ios`

Comment: This is really important, and I'm surprised more people haven't pointed this out.
If you're using Firebase, you probably need to use static linkage as well, so this may be a must.

Comment: this answer fixed my project issue

Comment: After adding these lines in the podfile I started to receive the following error: 
"10 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64"

Answer (score 5):

They have mentioned about this issue in the documentation and also suggested a fix for the same and it works. Clearing the Xcode cache worked for me :)

Solution:

> If you see a No permission handler detected error: Make sure that you
> have at least one permission handler set up. In some cases the Xcode
> cache needs to be cleared (Xcode -> Product -> Clean Build Folder)

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, your Podfile is not configured to handle permissions. In your Podfile under your target, add the relevant lines of code for the permissions you are requesting:

```
target 'LocalMainStreet' do

  # react-native-permissions permission handlers
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

  pod 'Permission-AppTrackingTransparency', :path => "#{permissions_path}/AppTrackingTransparency.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-BluetoothPeripheral', :path => "#{permissions_path}/BluetoothPeripheral.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Calendars', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Calendars.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Contacts', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Contacts.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-FaceID', :path => "#{permissions_path}/FaceID.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-MediaLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/MediaLibrary.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Microphone', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Microphone.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Motion', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Motion.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Reminders', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Reminders.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Siri', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Siri.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-SpeechRecognition', :path => "#{permissions_path}/SpeechRecognition.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-StoreKit', :path => "#{permissions_path}/StoreKit.podspec"

end
```

You can read more about it in the [react-native-permissions repo](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions#%EF%B8%8F-if-you-encounter-the-error-invalid-rnpermission-x-should-be-one-of--be-one-of-).

Comment: The paths have changed. My camera podspec was at `../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/Camera/Permission-Camera.podspec`

Answer (score 4):

The path changed. Now its ok. See below:

```
# permissions 
  pod 'Permission-BluetoothPeripheral', :path => "#{permissions_path}/BluetoothPeripheral/Permission-BluetoothPeripheral.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Calendars', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Calendars/Permission-Calendars.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera/Permission-Camera.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Contacts', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Contacts/Permission-Contacts.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-FaceID', :path => "#{permissions_path}/FaceID/Permission-FaceID.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways/Permission-LocationAlways.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse/Permission-LocationWhenInUse.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-MediaLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/MediaLibrary/Permission-MediaLibrary.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Microphone', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Microphone/Permission-Microphone.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Motion', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Motion/Permission-Motion.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications/Permission-Notifications.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary/Permission-PhotoLibrary.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Reminders', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Reminders/Permission-Reminders.podspec"
  pod 'Permission-Siri', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Siri/Permission-Siri.podspec"
```

Comment: Did you change something for it to be "ok"? Perhaps explain what I'm looking at below?

Answer (score 4):

#### iOS

By default no permission handler is installed. Update your `Podfile` by choosing the **ones** you want to check or request, then run `pod install`.

```rb
target 'YourAwesomeProject' do

  # …

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

  pod 'Permission-AppTrackingTransparency', :path => "#{permissions_path}/AppTrackingTransparency"
  pod 'Permission-BluetoothPeripheral', :path => "#{permissions_path}/BluetoothPeripheral"
  pod 'Permission-Calendars', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Calendars"
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
  pod 'Permission-Contacts', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Contacts"
  pod 'Permission-FaceID', :path => "#{permissions_path}/FaceID"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAccuracy', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAccuracy"
  pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways"
  pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse"
  pod 'Permission-MediaLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/MediaLibrary"
  pod 'Permission-Microphone', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Microphone"
  pod 'Permission-Motion', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Motion"
  pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibrary"
  pod 'Permission-PhotoLibraryAddOnly', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibraryAddOnly"
  pod 'Permission-Reminders', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Reminders"
  pod 'Permission-Siri', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Siri"
  pod 'Permission-SpeechRecognition', :path => "#{permissions_path}/SpeechRecognition"
  pod 'Permission-StoreKit', :path => "#{permissions_path}/StoreKit"

end
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue and realized that regardless all configurations I was missing to "setup" the permissions.

Based on that, if you have done everything mentioned on other answers and it still didn't work, make sure you ran `npx react-native setup-ios-permissions` followed by `pod install`.

Comment: I ran that command and cleaned the project including `pod install`. Still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because I forgot to do:

```
npx pod-install
//or
cd ios
pod-install
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Vaibhav Herugu's answer::

- Ensure the `react-native-permissions` package is installed. For Podfile tweaks? follow the instruction guide here:: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions
- Uninstall the app on your device
- You can delete the Xcode DerivedData folder directly from the terminal:
  `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
- Rebuild your app and smile :) (Hopefully)

Comment: I missed critical information for configuring permissions. If you find yourself with these errors, double-check the doc.

Answer (score 1):

at very first do close your simulator then run `npx react-native setup-ios-permissions` then `cd ios` then `pod install` then `cd ..` and run your project `npx react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of configuring each Pod file,

Install react-native-permissions by running a command

```
npm i react-native-permissions
```

or

```
yarn add react-native-permissions
```

This will install the react-native-permissions package. Then in ios/Podfile

```
use_react_native!(
)

##....

pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

##....
```

This will add the required Pods to the iOS project.

Then run

```
cd ios
pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have same issue I got the solution.

you just need to update that package. Previously i'm using `3.2.0` version of that package and I continuously face that issue.

with the help of **@Developerusman** I resolve this issue while updating Package to `"react-native-permissions": "^3.10.1",`

also you can check this out [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions/issues/449)

First thing you have to paste this code in podfile:

```
permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways/Permission-LocationAlways.podspec"
pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse/Permission-LocationWhenInUse.podspec"
pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
pod 'Permission-Contacts', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Contacts"
pod 'Permission-LocationAccuracy', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAccuracy"
pod 'Permission-MediaLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/MediaLibrary"
pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications"
pod 'Permission-PhotoLibraryAddOnly', :path => "#{permissions_path}/PhotoLibraryAddOnly"
```

I hope It can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with **React Native 0.63.2**.

The Solution was

1 - to **update my cocopods** version with

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

2 - **remove** the following code from my pod file

```
pre_install do |installer|
  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    if pod.name.eql?('RNPermissions') || pod.name.start_with?('Permission-')
      def pod.build_type;
        # Uncomment one line depending on your CocoaPods version
        Pod::BuildType.static_library # >= 1.9
        #Pod::Target::BuildType.static_library # < 1.9
      end
    end
  end
end
```

After that, I did a pod install and everything was working again.

Comment: This is correct as a work around when you use the `user_frameworks!` directive, as you can se in the [documentation diff](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions/commit/8e7c47d1cb0d0ab693636ac903b492a8e6aa7a42#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5L132).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, delete the build folder and rebuild then everything is go success.

Answer (score 0):

May 2023

Upgrading to the latest React Native version (0.71.8) fixed this for me.

Comment: Then your issue was probably unrelated because I'm running 0.72.3 and get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I add the geolocation service and update the info.plist file
after that, I have to get the same problem that you mentioned in the image

Steps that I have followed through the `react-native-permission` document that's work for me

I add this code to the package.json file.
In the reactNativePermissionsIOS object, you can add those things you want to access mentioned in the document

```js
"reactNativePermissionsIOS": [
    "Camera",
    "PhotoLibrary",
    "LocationWhenInUse"
  ],
```

and then add in info.plist that you want to access

```js
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Talemi marakiz needs to access the image gallery</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Talemi marakiz need to access camera</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Talemi marakiz needs to access your location</string>
```

**I read the react-native-permission document for ios**
[React Native Permission for ios](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions#ios)

**In the documentation, you need something to be noted. after setup all the things you must need to run this `npx react-native setup-ios-permissions` in your terminal**

I set up all those things but forgot to run this specific code so I get an error.
In my case after run this `npx react-native setup-ios-permissions` error resolve

Comment: I still can't get it running. I have added following handler in the Podfile
`permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'`

`pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications/Permission-Camera.podspec"`
`

I get following error.

`duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_RNPermissionHandlerCamera._reject'`

followed by

`4 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64.`

Answer (score -5):

In your node_modules

go into this file -> `react-native-permission`, then find the file `RNPermissions.m`  (could be inside the ios folder)

In this file Search for "No permission handler detected"
and comment this line "RCTLogError(@"%@", message)"

Then you're good to go for now.